# How to extract the Theme from a site in PnP provisioning for SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, pnp-provision

I am looking to extract a template with its theme from a site in SP Online. I have the code

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Configuration "template.json" -Out "template.xml" -Force
```

and for the template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/sppnp-extract-configuration-schema",
    "persistAssetFiles": false,
    "handlers": [
        "Lists",
        "WebSettings",
        "Pages",
        "Theme"
    ],
    "lists": {
        "lists": [
            {
                "title": "Banner",
                "includeItems": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "navigation": {
        "removeExistingNodes": true
    },
    "siteFooter": {
        "removeExistingNodes": true
    },
    "pages": {
        "includeAllClientSidePages": true
    }
}
```

But when I save the file, there is no `<pnp:Theme>` element. However before I extracted it, I set a site theme on the site. Anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theme is not in the list of handlers:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.framework.provisioning.model.handlers?view=sharepoint-pnpcoreol-3.2.1810

Comment: Yes it is, the docs must be outdated. If you go to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/pnp/provisioning/201910/extract-configuration.schema.json, the second last one above SiteSettings is `Theme`. Additionally, if I manually add the `<pnp:Theme>` afterwards to the extracted xml, it will get set when applying to the site.

Comment: While I appreciate the above schema, this does not mean that the functionality to extract the theme actually exists in the Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate cmdlet. You could however raise this as a bug on GitHub.